# XSLT use variable/parameter in XPATH

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to declare a variable/parameter in the beginning of my XSL sheet and use it later to filter on in XPATH:

```xml
<xsl:param name="MemberName">Lara</xsl:param>
<!-- other stuff -->
<xsl:for-each select="LIBRARY/MEMBER[MEMBER_NAME = '$MemberName']">
<!-- other stuff -->
```

but the resulting output is empty, whereas if I replace `'$MemberName'` with `'Lara'` it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is looking for a `MEMBER` whose `MEMBER_NAME` is the literal string `"$MemberName"`.

To look for a `MEMBER` whose `MEMBER_NAME` is equal to the value of the `$MemberName` param, remove the quotes surrounding the param name:

```
<xsl:for-each select="LIBRARY/MEMBER[MEMBER_NAME = $MemberName]">
```